# Unexpected output of expanded value of counter in aux file, when using \DeclareCaptionFormat

Tags: captions

I'm trying to circumvent the message prompt by the caption package, saying that an unknown class or package is messing with the `\caption` macro. I'm required to expand a value of a counter to then write to the aux file within the definition of `\caption`.

My original approach was something like this (this is an extremely mutilated version of the real thing):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\def\cm@namedef{\global\@namedef}
\newcount\caption@counter@i \caption@counter@i\z@
\LetLtxMacro{\oldcaption}{\caption}
\def\caption#1{%
\global\advance\caption@counter@i\@ne
  \ifnum\caption@counter@i>2
    \global\caption@counter@i=\@ne
\fi
\savecaptionposition
\oldcaption{#1}}%
\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}%
\def\savecaptionposition{%
\expandafter\protected@write
\expandafter\@auxout
\expandafter{%
\expandafter}%
\expandafter{%
\expandafter\string
\expandafter\cm@namedef
\expandafter{%
\the\caption@counter@i%
}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
a4a4a4a4
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
a4a4a4a4
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Looking at the aux file, the output (on TL2014, maximum updated installation) is

```
\relax 
\cm@namedef{1}{}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Test}}{1}}
\cm@namedef{2}{}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Test}}{1}}
```

(Pay attention to the values 1 and 2 in inside the first argument of `\cm@namedef`.

Perhaps I was naive to think that this should yield the exact same output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\def\cm@namedef{\global\@namedef}
\newcount\caption@counter@i \caption@counter@i\z@
\DeclareCaptionFormat{cmfix}{%
\global\advance\caption@counter@i\@ne
  \ifnum\caption@counter@i>2
    \global\caption@counter@i=\@ne
\fi
\savecaptionposition
#1#2#3}%
\captionsetup{format={cmfix},font={footnotesize}}%
\def\savecaptionposition{%
\expandafter\protected@write
\expandafter\@auxout
\expandafter{%
\expandafter}%
\expandafter{%
\expandafter\string
\expandafter\cm@namedef
\expandafter{%
\the\caption@counter@i%
}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
a4a4a4a4
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
a4a4a4a4
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

It doesn't: the output of the aux file is as follows...

```
\relax 
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Test\relax }}{1}}
\cm@namedef{2}{}
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {2}{\ignorespaces Test\relax }}{1}}
\cm@namedef{2}{}
```

In this case the expanded value of the counter is 2 in both cases.

Why does this happen, and how can I mimic the same behaviour as case 1?

Here's an MWE in which you can quickly see the difference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\makeatletter
\def\cm@namedef{\global\@namedef}
\newcount\caption@counter@i \caption@counter@i\z@
\LetLtxMacro{\oldcaption}{\caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{cmfix}{% uncomment this line
%\def\caption#1{% comment this line
\global\advance\caption@counter@i\@ne
  \ifnum\caption@counter@i>2
    \global\caption@counter@i=\@ne
\fi
\savecaptionposition
%\oldcaption{#1}}% comment this line
#1#2#3}% uncomment this line
\captionsetup{format={cmfix},font={footnotesize}}% uncomment this line
%\captionsetup{font={footnotesize}}% comment this line
\def\savecaptionposition{%
\typeout{[SCP] Counter I is \the\caption@counter@i}%
\expandafter\protected@write
\expandafter\@auxout
\expandafter{%
\expandafter}%
\expandafter{%
\expandafter\string
\expandafter\cm@namedef
\expandafter{%
\the\caption@counter@i%
}{}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
a4a4a4a4
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
a4a4a4a4
\caption{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You're not taking into account the fact that a caption is typeset twice, for checking whether it fits in a line and so center it.

Comment: When dealing with the `caption` package anyway, you could try to re-define an internal macro of the `caption` package instead of `\caption`, e.g.: `\let\ORI@caption@refstepcounter\caption@refstepcounter\def\caption@refstepcounter{...(your stuff)\ORI@caption@refstepcounter}`